# id Token vs access_token google login api in web

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, nestjs, google-oauth

I was using `access_token` after sign in with Google, but the Google login has changed and I am trying to use it as `id_token`.

I received the `email` and `id` through the existing code below.

```js
const userInfoClient = google.oauth2('v2').userinfo;

      this.oauthClient.setCredentials({
        access_token: tokenData.token,
      });

      const userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.get({
        auth: this.oauthClient,
      });
```

The changed code is as follows.
I receive various values ​​through the payload.
I need `email` and `id`, but `id` value does not exist. Is `nbf` equal to `id` in `access_token`?

```js
const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
          idToken: tokenData.token,
          audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        });
```

payload has values ​​such as iss,nbf,aud,sub,email,azp,name,picture,iat,exp,jti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nbf` stands for "Not Before" and it's a timestamp that specifies the time before which token cannot be used. The `sub` means "Subject" and is usually the user's UID that you might be looking for. Checkout [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2) to learn more about the properties present in a JWT.

Comment: thank you for your reply! So, is it correct to use sub?

Comment: @KunAguero yes, it's unique for each user. In case of Firebase Auth/Identity Toolkit `sub` is User's UID. You can log and check that once but reset assured it must be unique as in the RFC.